# Unknow reason for multiple Mysql Entries

Tags: c#, mysql, service

I have a service which retrieve historical data and saves it in MySQL table

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

            //Get Relevant Gateways
            string GetRouters = "SELECT * FROM RouterModel;";
            var Routers = await dataAccess.LoadData<RouterModel, dynamic>(GetRouters, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("MainDB"));

            string GetMeters = "SELECT * FROM PowerMeterModel;";
            var Meters = await dataAccess.LoadData<PowerMeterModel, dynamic>(GetMeters, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("MainDB"));


            foreach (RouterModel Router in Routers)
            {
                if (Router.IsHavePowerMeters)
                {
                    foreach (PowerMeterModel Meter in Meters.Where(x => x.IdGateway == Router.Id).ToList())
                    {
                        if (Meter.IsActive)
                        {
                            actionList.Add(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                GetHistory(Router, Meter);
                                _logger.LogInformation("Synced History meter:" + Meter.SerialNumber.ToString());

                                
                            }));

                            
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            Parallel.Invoke(actionList.ToArray());
            actionList.Clear();

            _logger.LogWarning("*************** Sync loop is finished ***************");

            await Task.Delay(60*1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }


    
    public async void GetHistory(RouterModel Router, PowerMeterModel Meter)
    {
        Web device = new() { IpAddress = Router.IpAddress, UserName = Meter.Username, Password = Meter.Password, Port = Meter.TcpPort };
        StringBuilder SqlQuery = new();
        StringBuilder TimeString = new();
        ElnetMcMapping elnetMcMapping = new();
        ElnetMcModel mcReadings = new();

        if (Meter.ModelClass == nameof(ElnetMcModel).ToString())
        {
            for (int day = 1; day < 4; day++)
            {
                List<List<double>> responeData = new();
                DateTime date = todayDate.AddDays(-day);

                for (int j = 0; j < elnetMcMapping.DataItems.Count; j += 8)
                {
                    var items = elnetMcMapping.DataItems.Skip(j).Take(8);
                    device.Items = items.Select(x => x.Address.ToString()).ToList();

                    var responseString = device.GetElnetReadings(httpClient, 2, date);
                    if (responseString != null)
                    {
                        int check = responeData.Count;
                        responeData.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<double>>>(responseString));

                    }
                    else { return; }
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < elnetMcMapping.DataItems.Count; j++) { elnetMcMapping.DataItems[j].Value = responeData[j]; }

                foreach (MetaData metaData in elnetMcMapping.DataItems)
                {
                    Type type = mcReadings.GetType();
                    PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(metaData.Label);

                    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(decimal)) { prop.SetValue(mcReadings, Convert.ToDecimal(metaData.Value[0]) * metaData.Multiplier, null); }
                    else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)) { prop.SetValue(mcReadings, metaData.Value[0].ToString(), null); }
                    else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int)) { prop.SetValue(mcReadings, int.Parse(metaData.Value[0].ToString()), null); }
                    else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)) { prop.SetValue(mcReadings, DateTime.Now, null); }
                    else { return; }
                }


                var propList = mcReadings.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
                SqlQuery.Append("INSERT INTO " + Meter.DataTableName + " (");
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propList) { SqlQuery.Append(prop.Name + ","); }
                SqlQuery.Remove(SqlQuery.Length - 1, 1);
                SqlQuery.Append(") VALUES (");
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propList)
                {
                    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)prop.GetValue(mcReadings);
                        SqlQuery.Append("'" + dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'" + ",");
                    }
                    else { SqlQuery.Append(prop.GetValue(mcReadings).ToString() + ","); }
                }
                SqlQuery.Remove(SqlQuery.Length - 1, 1);
                SqlQuery.Append(");");

                await dataAccess.SaveData(SqlQuery.ToString(), mcReadings, _config.GetConnectionString("PwrMeterDb"));

            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

The above code should add only 4 MySql rows, instead I get 6, it seems like the whole method
is starting all over again for each time the loop `for (int day = 1; day < 4; day++)`
cahnges its value.

Instead getting 4 rows (one for each day) I get 6

Instead getting 5 rows (one for each day) I get 10

Instead getting 6 rows (one for each day) I get 15

Instead getting 7 rows (one for each day) I get 21

Any ideas what could be wrong ?

Comment: Try putting breakpoints and debug each sql result and loop.

Comment: @AliK does not work, at one point it just skips forward after a few interations and I get what I get....

Comment: Also: Maybe take the time and split that bowl of spaghetti up in small testable functions and then: write tests. Do all parts do, what you think they do?

Comment: Take out the looping while debugging. It will mess up the session if you take longer than the delay.

Comment: I have another function almost Identical, the only thing I changed is the loop and it works fine for (int i = 0; i < Meter.ThreePhaseCH; i++)

Comment: async void is a no-no, ... Parallel.Invoke _may_ be an issue ... so much here, that I'd personally would strip it down and build it up again one part at a time.

Comment: Generally, mixing Parallel.Invoke and async is ... well, let's say "they don't get along very well".

Comment: @Fildor well I tried to remove the "async" and the "await" in the end but this did not make any diffrence. It acts like there is another loop sitting on top of the other and I just can't find the reason why, all I did is to duplicate a perefctly working code and changed the paramter for each the loop is iterating over

Comment: For one - I honestly doubt "the duplicated code" is "working perfectly fine" and then You have a lot of async and parallel intermingled here. Looks like _waaaayy_ too early optimization. Try doing all tasks in sequence. Then see if you still see the excess rows.

Comment: And again: Better refactor to smaller pieces of which you can easily see if what comes out matches what you expect from what you put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing the `SqlQuery` `StringBuilder` object at the beginning of each loop.

So, in the first iteration, it has one `INSERT` query. In the second iteration, it has two, for a total of three INSERTs. In the third iteration, it has three, for a total of six. In the fourth iteration, it has four INSERTs, for a total of ten. This produces the 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21 sequence you're observing.

Call `SqlQuery.Clear()` at the beginning of each loop.